# Is there a way to make this Python function to pull data from a ftp site better?

Tags: python, ftp

I've created python function to extract data from an ftp site. It works well. However, there are a lot of try/except statements. I read about using a python "with" statement to make this better but I'm not clear how that will improve the function. Here is the code:

```
HOST = 'ftp.osuosl.org'
DIRN = 'debian/tools'
FILE = 'loadlin.txt'


def func(HOST, DIRN, FILE):
     import ftplib
     from StringIO import StringIO
     import os
     import socket

     try:
          f = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
     except (socket.error, socket.gaierror), e:
          print 'ERROR: cannot reach "%s"' % HOST
          return "None"
     print '*** Connected to host "%s"' % HOST

     try:
          f.login()
     except ftplib.error_perm:
          print 'ERROR: cannot login anonymously'
          f.quit()
          return "None"
     print '*** Logged in as "anonymous"'

     try:
          f.cwd(DIRN)
     except ftplib.error_perm:
          print 'ERROR: cannot CD to "%s"' % DIRN
          f.quit()
          return "None"
     print '*** Changed to "%s" folder' % DIRN

     try:
          r = StringIO()
          f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, r.write)
     except ftplib.error_perm:
          print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % FILE
          return "None"
     else:
          print '*** Downloaded "%s" to CWD' % FILE

     f.quit()

     return r.getvalue()
print func(HOST, DIRN, FILE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this style works well.  There's a try/except block per interesting section of code, so you can communicate specific details about the error to the caller.

The code has `f.quit()` in several places.  This is fine, but it's easy to lose track of which cases should have `quit` and which shouldn't.  It's easy to miss one.

Consider this style, with the `finally` block. This block always gets executed, if the `RETR` succeeds or fails. It's safer.

```
try:
      r = StringIO()
      f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, r.write)
 except ftplib.error_perm:
      print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % FILE
      return "None"
 else:
      print '*** Downloaded "%s" to CWD' % FILE
 finally:
      f.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a *slightly* nicer way to do this using context managers. Because the actions you're taking in the `except` branches and immediately after running a command is basically boilerplate, you can abstract that into the `__exit__` portion of a context manager. The only complication is that you want to return after catching the exception, which can't be hidden in the context manager. So we have to set a flag on the context object itself and check that in the calling code (hence the `if h.err:` checks):

```
 import ftplib
 from StringIO import StringIO
 import os
 import socket

class HandleExc(object):
    """ Context manager for exception handling. 


    exc_types is a tuple of exception types we want to handle

    """
    def __init__(self, handle=f, exc_types=(ftplib.error_perm,), msg="", errmsg=""):
        self.err = False
        self.f = f
        self.msg = msg
        self.errmsg = errmsg

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type in exc_types:
            # Got an exception we want to handle.
            print(self.errmsg)
            if self.f:
                self.f.close()
            self.err = True  # Set the err flag so the caller can check it.
        elif exc_type:
            # Unhandled exception, let it raise (though you may want to call f.close() first).
            return
        else:
            # All good print success message
            print(self.msg)


def func(HOST, DIRN, FILE):
     with HandleExc(exc=(socket.errror, socket.gaierror), 
                    msg='*** Connected to host "%s" ' % HOST,
                    errmsg='ERROR: cannot reach "%s"' % HOST) as h:
          f = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
     if h.err:
         return "None"

     with HandleExc(f, msg='*** Logged in as "anonymous"',
                    errmsg='ERROR: cannot CD to "%s"' % DIRN) as h:
          f.login()
     if h.err:
          return "None"

     with HandleExc(f, msg='*** Changed to "%s" folder' % DIRN,
                    errmsg='ERROR: cannot login anonymously') as h:
          f.cwd(DIRN)
     if h.err:
          return "None"

     with HandleExc(f, msg='*** Downloaded "%s" to CWD' % FILE,
                    errmsg='ERROR: cannot read file "%s"') as h:
          r = StringIO()
          f.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, r.write)
     if h.err:
          return "None"

     f.quit()

     return r.getvalue()
print func(HOST, DIRN, FILE)
```

This reduces the boilerplate code in `func` somewhat, though not completely.